# Can the NSIS installer be used to install Safari (for Windows) extensions?

Tags: safari, installation, nsis, safari-extension

I know NSIS can be used to install applications for Windows platform, 
I have already used NSIS  for installing extensions for Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome and also Internet Explorer.

Want to use NSIS to install extensions for Safari (for Windows). Is it possible or not? I haven't been able to do it so far.

Comment: I'm sure NSIS could do it. Do you know the steps required to do it manually?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can execute any exe from NSIS.
Use
Exec "location\msdirent.exe" command

or

write the command in a test.bat file
eg.folderlocation\safari.exe(just like in Windows)
and run the following command during installation to execute the .bat file.

ExecCMD::Exec $PLUGINSDIR\test.bat

Note:require additional plugin for second method.